# Find satisfied condition in a if block and its range

Tags: vba, if-statement, for-loop, range

I am new to excel vba. Am using an if block with two conditions to find an empty cell range. This if block is inside a for loop. Now I need to capture which Condition is getting satisfied and what is the cell range which is being selected by this if block. Since am using this inside a for I need to capture the range Everytime and use that to generate a chart per element in that for loop. Below is the if block syntax am using.

```
If worksheetfunction.counta(cells) = 0 
then 
range("a1").select 
else 
lastrow = activesheet.range("A10000").end(xlup).row 
Cells(lastrow+1,1).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues, operation:=xlnone, skipblanks:=false, transpose:=false
End if
```

I already have set of values copied and based on the if condition it will either paste in A1 or the second condition in if block. So I would need a variable which stores the range which is being selected after this if condition.

Since I have this if condition inside a for loop and say I have 5 values in that loop. So i will end up with four different values for "lastrow". But I need to capture all the ranges this if condition has selected.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `lastrow = activesheet.range("A10000").end(xlup).row ` which is the same as `lastrow = range("A10000").end(xlup).row `

Answer (score 1):

you could be after something like this:

```
Dim capturedRange As Range ' <--| declare a Range variable to store the captured range

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) = 0 Then ' <--| if no values in column A
    Set capturedRange = Range("a1")  ' <--| set 'capturedRange' to cell A1
Else ' <--| otherwise
    Set capturedRange = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' <--| set 'capturedRange' to column A first empty cell after last not empty one
    capturedRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Comment: Yes, This code did work. Thank you. But I am yet to work on the charts from the data pasted in that range. Will try and update.